# Onde esta o erro?

Tags: php, mysql

```
     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 if($row['level'] = '0')
 {
 echo("Fundador '); //pode fazer tudo
 }

  if($row['level'] = '1')
 {
 echo('Admin'); //  nao pode adicionar nem remover e/ou edit users
 }

      if($row['level'] = '2')
     {
        echo('Moderador de canais'); //n tem acesso a pagina de jogos e filmes
     }

          if($row['level'] = '3')
     {
        echo('Moderador de jogos'); // n tem acesso a pagina canais e filmes
     }
          if($row['level'] = '4')
     {
        echo('Moderador de filmes'); //n tem acesso a pagina de canais e jogos.
     }
 else
 {
 echo("Membro'); //sem permissoes p ver as paginas
 }
}
```

Comment: Aqui está o erro aparentemente, você abre uma aspas duplas e fecha uma simples nessa linha: `echo("Fundador ');` e nessa outra `echo("Membro');`. Pare evitar esse tipo de erro utilize uma IDE ou editor de texto com highlight, você pode ver uma lista [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) além de outras dicas de php.

Comment: Oi Rodrigo, bem-vindo ao site. Talvez você esteja surpreso com a repercussão negativa da sua pergunta. Infelizmente não tenho poderes mentais pra te dizer o motivo de cada voto contra. Mas posso dizer que a falta de indentação do seu código é um possível motivo. Indentar corretamente e usar ferramentas como um editor que marque o código com cores são fundamentais para perceber esse tipo de erro, não só para principiantes, mas para qualquer programador. Quem negativou a pergunta deve ter considerado que você não fez o mínimo esforço sozinho antes de perguntar para os outros.

Comment: Ao postar uma pergunta aqui, também é importante mostrar a mensagem de erro que aparece pra você. Isso facilita muito a vida de quem for tentar te ajudar. Se você não posta a mensagem de erro, quem quer ajudar terá mais trabalho. A falta da mensagem, somada ao seu título mínimo, pode ser outro motivo para os votos contra. Tente ser mais específico no título. Pense que sua pergunta pode vir a ajudar outras pessoas além de você, se for bem escrita. Por fim, vale uma visita ao nosso [tour] e à [help]. Lá você entenderá melhor as diferenças deste site para os fóruns tradicionais.

Comment: E não esqueça também de visitar o [Manual de como não fazer perguntas!](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas?cb=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe mais de um erro, do modo como está sempre que um registro não for do level 4 ele caíra no else.

Também existe erro no fechamento de aspas em duas linhas (5 e 30)

O código correto seria:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($row['level'] = '0') {
        echo("Fundador"); //pode fazer tudo
    }
    else if ($row['level'] = '1') {
        echo('Admin'); //  nao pode adicionar nem remover e/ou edit users
    }
    else if ($row['level'] = '2') {
        echo('Moderador de canais'); //n tem acesso a pagina de jogos e filmes
    }
    else if ($row['level'] = '3') {
        echo('Moderador de jogos'); // n tem acesso a pagina canais e filmes
    }
    else if ($row['level'] = '4') {
        echo('Moderador de filmes'); //n tem acesso a pagina de canais e jogos.
    } 
    else {
        echo("Membro"); //sem permissoes p ver as paginas
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Está na sua linha 5:

```
echo("Fundador '); //pode fazer tudo
```

Você está abrindo com aspas duplas e fechando com aspas simples.
Troque o ' por " e voltará a funcionar, assim:

```
echo("Fundador"); //pode fazer tudo
```